# Programs can't modify files on Windows, but can create new ones

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs

After a fresh installation of Windows on my new M2 drive and reinstalling all programs, I'm facing an issue where most programs can't modify existing files, for example Photoshop can't “Save”, but it can “Save As” a new file. DaVinci Resolve can't save its presets unless it runs as admin, etc…

I have only 1 account on my PC and it is admin.
The permissions are set up correctly I'm pretty sure:

Current Windows Permissions on my D: Drive:

[image]

Comment: Try a new, test User Account and see if the issue is the same in a new profile.

Comment: We don't need "SOLVED" in your title. In a couple of days you will be able to accept your answer using the tick mark beside it to mark your problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Avast interfering for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

You have modified the permissions of the hard disk.
This is what your image should have looked like:

[image]

I suggest to format the hard disk and reinstall Windows.
Don't do manually any permission changes, they are not
required for Windows to function.
Let Windows assign its own permissions.